# Visual Studio 2010 C#

Tags: visual-studio

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать? Дана форма1, Форма2, есть кнопка1 на Форме1, при нажатии ее открывается Форма2. Как сделать, чтоб при этом закрылась Форма1.

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    new Form2().ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

В методе `public static void Main(...)` у вас наверняка написано что-нибудь следующее:

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

Таким образом, сделать то, что вы просите по-простому не получится *(простой вариант - это вызвать `this.Close();`)*

Это связано с тем, что [**метод Run**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms157902.aspx) при своем вызове делает так, что объект формы `Form1` становится **основной формой для приложения,** т.е ее закрытие ведет к автоматическому выходу из этого приложения.

Вы можете скрыть эту форму на время модального вызова `Form2`, как, например, описано [**здесь.**](http://ruel.me/blog/2010/09/17/csharp-hide-main-form/) Или же *вам придется точнее описать*, что вы хотите сделать, т.к для лично для меня модальный вызов новой формы и одновременное закрытие основной формы выглядит как нонсенс.

Answer (score 1):

this.Close();

Comment: не срабатывает..(

Comment: Хотя нет =) Так сделать не получится.. Дело в том, что когда Вы с родительской формы вызываете дотчернюю, родительскую форму закрыть нельзя ибо в ней хранятся все ссылки и ресурсы для дочерней формы. Думаю нужно будет создавать отдельный процесс..